# Rails 4.2 console issues - using RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-console

trying to run

```
$ rails c RAILS_ENV=development
```

1 warning and 1 error are raised which I do not understand

```
# warning :
  config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

# error
/config/initializers/devise.rb:13:in `+': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

However , the config.eager_load is set to false in the development environment

```
config/environment/development.rb
  Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  …/…
```

And looking at the config/initializers/devise.rb ( line 13) I have

```
config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
   …/…
  (13)  config.mailer_sender = 'no-reply@' +    Rails.application.secrets.domain_name
   …/…
```

which lead to the config/secrets.yml file

```
config/secrets.yml
  development:
      domain_name: example.com
```

it's quite understandable , as running rails c ( whithout RAILS_ENV) , I get

```
$ rails c
  development environment (Rails 4.2.3)
  irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context.
  irb(main):001:0>  Rails.application.secrets.domain_name
```

=> "example.com"

this warning is also cryptic :

> irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context

could not find any info on Google search... but at least it runs in development ....

why this warning and error using RAILS_ENV ?  any enlightenment welcome

Answer (score 0):

too bad .. I should HAVE READ the latest 4.2 doc !!!
so I should NOT be using RAILS_ENV at all !!

$ rails console staging
Loading staging environment (Rails 4.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> exit

$ rails console development
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.3)
irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context.
irb(main):001:0> exit